# Not Getting $ in command prompt in Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

My NodeJs is working fine but i have an issue I'm not seeing $ in the prompt as most example point.

Another issue is when i put sudo I dont get anything.Things I have tried are the following

$ sudo npm install npm -g
/usr/bin/npm -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@2.7.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm

given on the following Website

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_npm.htm

Apologies am very new to Node.JS.Please help

Comment: Are you running node on a mac or win?

Comment: The $ is only there to represent a new command in the terminal.

Comment: Note: The `$` is included as a convention for representing a command prompt in documentation. It's likely based on the `$` (or `#`) marker often displayed in linux/unix shells (defined by the `\$` escape in [prompt variables](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html)). You shouldn't actually type it as part of the command.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments New to javascript programing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to explain this in terms familiar to MS windows.

$ npm --version

^ dollar sign is the same as "C:\" in windows.
It just means "from here..." in the most basic terms I can use.
You don't need the dollar sign for anything in that tutorial.

"sudo" means "elevate to an administrator level" similar to opening a command line terminal "in administrator mode." But for Linux (Ubuntu and Mac as *NIX) systems.

--version can be called as "-v" most of the time and means "for the thing I've named before, in this case "npm" show me the version.

Once you've installed NodeJS it comes with a "package manager" called NPM.  The best way to relate this to windows is by considering it a command line version of an "installation" that installs different programs as you tell it to with different options.

"npm install -g" means "Hey NPM! Install to EVERYWHERE(call from command line/terminal/bash) the thing I Tell you next.  "npm install -g express" for example, means hey NPM, install "expressJS" globally, so I can use the terminal to write commands(micro apps) from the expressJS I just installed with node.

"npm install --save" means hey, install this microapp, but ONLY let me use it in THIS EXACT FOLDER I'm in, and let anyone else that is in this folder know they need to install it to use this application I'm making.

"npm init" Is actually the FIRST thing you should do in any node project folder.  It creates the "package.json" file in the current directory, and it will define the folder you're in as the folder to start installing stuff you "npm install" to the "node_modules" folder that will show in the folder you're currently in.

If you want to tinker with NodeJS code, and you don't want to tamper with your local machine and install all kinds of stuff you're not totally sure about yet you can use "REPL.it" (https://repl.it/languages/nodejs) the white window on the right is treated like a file you'd run in node. The dark window on the right is an actual NODE TERMINAL that you can run nodejs commands/code in directly.

There's one other good resources in general and that is here (https://devdocs.io/) it's called "Devdocs" and it has Node, npm, and express code examples, clean explanations, and examples that you can download directly to your local machine.

I hope that gets you moving with NodeJS.  It's hard to understand, but with a bit of try and fail you'll start to try more and fail less.  Cheers!